# Send Json data to controller

Tags: json, laravel-4

I am sending some data as cat_id into here

```
$.get('/ajax3?cat_id=' +cat_id,function(data){});
```

I want to send multiple data like cat_id, sub_id How can I do this:

```
<script>
$("#cat3").on('click',function (e) {
//console.log(e);

var cat_id=document.getElementById('cat').value;
var sub_id=document.getElementById('sub').value;

    $.get('/ajax3?cat_id=' +cat_id,function(data)
    {
        $('#sub1').empty();
        $.each(data,function(index,subcatObj)
        {
            $('#sub1').append('<li>'+subcatObj.section+'</li>');
        })

    });
});
```

In my controller i get cat_id that i send. Now I want to pass `sub_id` how do I do this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that sounds pretty simple. You just add `sub_id` to the query string:

```
$("#cat3").on('click',function (e) {
//console.log(e);

var cat_id=document.getElementById('cat').value;
var sub_id=document.getElementById('sub').value;

    $.get('/ajax3?cat_id=' +cat_id + '&sub_id=' + sub_id  ,function(data)
    {
        $('#sub1').empty();
        $.each(data,function(index,subcatObj)
        {
            $('#sub1').append('<li>'+subcatObj.section+'</li>');
        })

    });
});
```

Then you can just use the **Input** Facade to get the parameter in your controller:

`Input::get('sub_id')`